# Display tamil unicode character set in java - Reg

Tags: java, netbeans

When i try to display tamil unicode character its just been displayed as a empty box. I use netbeans and i checked for the encoding option as UTF-8 in the project properties also i have set in the project.properties file runtime encoding as UTF-8. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are the propert fonts installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Does the font you use on your computer include the full unicode characterset? If not characters will be displayed as a box by your OS.